# How to pass 2 variables in Anchor tag Invisible to user using POST or whatever with PHP

Tags: php, post, get

I can pass two variables page to page via,..

In HTML:
Pass 5 and 9

In PHP:
echo " Pass 5 and 9
 ";

And retrieve them with $_GET

BUT the data is visible to the user
How can I do this so the data is not visible to the user?

I'm assuming I should use POST but really need some sample code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at php sessions

Answer (score 0):

Sessions might be what you are looking for.

//then at any point you can set a session variable
$_SESSION['new_var'] = $_POST['new'];

Comment: Roger. That should do it. Thanks.